# Excel 2010 not inheriting regional settings from Windows 8.1

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, windows-8.1, regional-settings

In regional settings of Windows 8.1, I have negative numbers set to display in accounting mode. e.g. `(1.0)` instead of `-1.0`.

Excel should be getting this setting as a default now, as it did in Windows 7, But apparently this no longer works.

I have done some searching online for a fix to no avail.  I wonder if anyone else has had this issue and has a possible solution.

NOTE: `CURRENCY` has also been changed in regional settings.

Comment: Really? am i the only one... :(

Answer (score 0):

I use different regional settings under windows 10 (update is free ;)) and it all works fine. I have also done this in Windows 8.1 before.

One idea to remedy your situation could be that you just use a different "output" style in excel? You can always use different cell styles (i.e. "Number formats") to show ($1) instead of $-1, e.g. Does it have to be the default for what you are trying to achieve?